# How to return list of items that will pass validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd

I have an Outlet model that has an inclusion validation that allows a couple of values, and that I will look to expand to have more values.

I was wondering if there is away to call a method that would return the array of values that I used in my inclusion validation?

```
class Outlet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments

  validates :category, :title, :body, :urgency, :user, presence: true
  validates :title, length: { in: 1..60 }
  validates :body, length: { in: 1..1000 }
  validates :urgency, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, less_than_or_equal_to: 10 }
  validates :category, inclusion: { in: ['vent', 'rant', 'qualm'] }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveModel` class method `validators_on` will return all validators for a given field. E.g.:

```
Outlet.validators_on(:category)
#=> [#<ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator:0x007fd2350e4b88 ...>, #<ActiveModel::Validations::InclusionValidator:0x007fd23a872cd8 ...>]
```

It allows to obtain inclusion values like this:

```
Outlet.validators_on(:category)
  .find { |validator| validator.is_a?(ActiveModel::Validations::InclusionValidator) }
  .options[:in]
```

It will return an array of options.

But a cleaner way to achieve the same would be to extract options to class constant:

```
class Outlet < ApplicationRecord
  ALLOWED_CATEGORIES = %w(vent rant qualm).freeze

  # ...

  validates :category, inclusion: { in: ALLOWED_CATEGORIES }
end
```

Then access allowed values via `Outlet::ALLOWED_CATEGORIES`

Comment: Great info. Thank you!